# Pyspark how to filter out the list full with null or sum of list equals to 0?

Tags: filter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pyspark, we can easily filter out the single null value in specific column by using something like:

```
df.filter("column is Not NULL")
```

However,in my case, the value in column becomes `[null,null,null]` or `[0,0,0]`
I would like to know how to filter out these two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below **`isNull()`** <- This will check if your column is null or not

**`df = df.filter(F.col("col_name").isNull())`**

In case you have a list column  - you can use **`array_contains`** - This will return **`true`** or **`false`**

**`df = df.withColumn("result", F.array_contains(df.col, "a"))`**
more [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html?highlight=array#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains)